# Layover in Addis Ababa: need to collect checked luggage?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, short-connections, addis-ababa

I'm going to travel from Mumbai to Durban on Ethopian airlines.  It is my first time traveling alone.  My layover in Addis Ababa is only 40 minutes.  Do I need to collect my luggage in Addis?

Comment: @RugDealer do you object to "min" as well, or only to "plz"?

Comment: No need to be rude .I'm not a experienced blogger I have never asked questions nor answered anything in such type of sites LOL "laugh out loud".But any way thanks it helped me alot 

Comment: @GeetanjaliNileshMaharaj Don't worry too much about it.  We have had some questions posted that were much harder to work with than yours.  Welcome to the site!  If you have any other questions about your first-time travel, if they're not already answered here, please post them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a layover in Addis a few days ago.  You do not necessarily have to collect your luggage there.  Confirm this with the airline agent when you check your bag(s).  The destination ticket should indicate Durban airport (DUR).

In addition, I can confirm that for an international transit, you do not need to clear Ethiopian immigration controls.